# where Has Condition on a hasMany relationship in Laravel 5.8

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.8, eloquent-relationship, php-7.3, wherehas

I have a relationship in a model FeeModuleModel as shown below

```
   public function heads()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Models\FeeHeadModel','location_id','id');
   }
```

and in my controller file i need to fetch only the values FeeModuleModel where the FeeHeadModel has type as unstructured
My controller code is as shown below

```
$modules = FeeModuleModel::where('vt_ay_id', '=', Session::get('sess_ay_id'))->with(['heads'=>function($q){ 
            $q->where('type','=','unstructured');
        }])->orderby('priority', 'asc')->get();
```

This fails with the following error

> Call to a member function getRelationExistenceQuery() on array

What is the problem with my code and what I can do to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code to this one

```
$modules = FeeModuleModel::with(['heads'=>function($q){ 
            $q->where('type','=','unstructured');
        }])->where('vt_ay_id', '=', Session::get('sess_ay_id'))->orderby('priority', 'asc')->get();
```